# Chrome : Stalled request is received twice on ec2 server

Tags: google-chrome, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, netflix-zuul

Sometime the request is getting stalled on Chrome, it takes different amount of time ranging from 3sec to 95sec as shown in the screenshots  below -

[image][image]

Usually, the API takes around 1sec to complete.
In cases where the request is stalled, we receive the request two times on the server. Hence, the operation is done twice.

UI is build on RectJs + Axios

BE service is behind ELB and running on EC2 containers.
There is Reverse proxy of Netflix zuul on edge.

Can someone please help, the request is received twice on the server in above mentioned case?

Comment: Are you sending requests in parallel or consecutively?

Comment: On this operation particularly, only 1 request is being sent. @ErmiyaEskandary

Comment: Is the issue the stalling or the 2x request?

Comment: I am concerned about 2x request but not sure if it is related to stalling. Although, a request stalled for 95 second is also a concern.

Comment: The occurrence of 2x is coinciding with stalled request. @ErmiyaEskandary